# PHP: Sorting three arrays using values from one of them. Vital for my Android/iPhone Apps

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am designing a PHP file to communicate with my Android/iPhone apps and encountered with a simple but difficult-to-solve problem for me.

**I have this function, which only takes three parameters( categories_id, categories_name, categories_picture ) from a DB ( MySQL ) and sends them to my app over a jSON response.** The thing is : Because one thing or the other the categories are not be sent in order ( by category_id ) , and I would like so.

**Question:** IS THERE A WAY TO ORDER THE THREE ARRAYS AT THE SAME TIME BY THE CATEGORIES_ID ?

**Example of current response:** 
categories_id = ( 4, 8, 2, 1 );
categories_name= ( Chairs, Tables, Lamps, Doors );
categories_picture=( www.xyz.com/photo4.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo8.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo2.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo1.jpg)
**Desired Response:**
categories_id = ( 1, 2, 4, 8 );
categories_name= ( Doors, Lamps, Chairs, Tables);
categories_picture=( www.xyz.com/photo1.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo2.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo4.jpg,www.xyz.com/photo8.jpg)

Have you seen how the three arrays changed based on the clasification by categories_id??

**CURRENT FUNCTION:**

```
if( $accion == 3 )
{    
    /*fetch category details from shop_category*/
    $sql = "select * from `shop_category` where `Stat` like 'Y' order by `CName`";
    $rec = @mysql_query( $sql );
    $row = @mysql_num_rows( $rec );**

    if( $row > 0 ) 
    {
        $path_to_link = 'category_pic/';
        while( $data = @mysql_fetch_array( $rec ) ) 
        {
            $categories_id[] = $data['C_ID'];
            $categories_name[] = stripslashes( $data['CName'] );
            $categories_picture[] = $domain.$path_to_link.$data['C_Image'];
        }

        $respond_categories = array( "categories_id"=>$categories_id, "categories_name"=>$categories_name, "categories_picture"=>$categories_picture );
        echo (json_encode($respond_categories)); 
    }

}
```

I would like to thank all of you who spent his time reading. Thanks.

If anyone is interested the app is called : Cae de Cajon in Google Play . It is only a beta for one of my clients.:) Proud of it. It is also available in Apple Store but it is not so up to date.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2):

This may have been one of the dummest questions ever. the anwser could be ?:

$sql = "select * from `shop_category` where `Stat` like 'Y' order by `CID`"; ??

I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the answer could be that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solution.you can use a counter in while loop instead of using C_ID for getting the desired response from database and it looks like

```
if( $accion == 3 )
{    
    /*fetch category details from shop_category*/
    $sql = "select * from `shop_category` where `Stat` like 'Y' order by `C_ID`";
    $rec = @mysql_query( $sql );
    $row = @mysql_num_rows( $rec );
if( $row > 0 ) 
{
    $path_to_link = 'category_pic/';

$i = 0;
while( $data = @mysql_fetch_array( $rec ) ) 
    {
        $category_array[] = $i;
    $categories_id[] = $data['C_ID'];
        $categories_name[] = stripslashes( $data['CName'] );
        $categories_picture[] = $domain.$path_to_link.$data['C_Image'];
    $i++;
    }

    $respond_categories = array( "category_array"=>$category_array,"categories_id"=>$categories_id, "categories_name"=>$categories_name, "categories_picture"=>$categories_picture );
    echo (json_encode($respond_categories)); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a order by clause in your query